# I don't receive the OTP code for changing bookings on IndiGo for international cell phone numbers

Tags: air-travel, india, indigo

I don't receive the OTP code when changing bookings on IndiGO website. The text field does not allow me to enter international phone numbers since these are a digit longer than Indian numbers. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The website does not tell you but you will receive an OTP code on your email for international numbers, even if you enter an incomplete number - so check your inbox!